# install-missing-android-tools@2.1.1 (exit code: 1) using Bitrise

Tags: android, bitrise

i deploy android application to bitrise while i getting the below error

error:install-missing-android-tools@2.1.1 (exit code: 1)

Answer (score 1):

This log line means that the `install-missing-android-tools` step (version `2.1.1`) failed.

To see why it failed you should check the rest of the log. If you need help with that then share the rest of the step's log here or contact bitrise support via email or the onsite chat! ;)

Comment: i'm also getting the same error is any soultion for that

Comment: @avezraj please contact the bitrise support via email or the onsite chat on bitrise.io - without additional information it's impossible to tell you what fails - this line `error:install-missing-android-tools@2.1.1 (exit code: 1)` means that the step failed, but without the rest of the log impossible to tell why.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. After run in terminal of Android Studio the command `:app:dependencies`, found a lib inside a lib that is getting error.

I solved my problem explicitaly implementating the follow libs in my build.gradle:

```
compile 'android.arch.core:common:1.1.1'
compile 'android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.1.1'
```

Hope this solve for you too.

Edit:
Another test I made was update every `com.google.android` compile version. That works for me too.